# Trying to print the output from my function inside my GUI window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im trying to make a little program that endlessly prints out numbers inside GUI window, I can not find a way to print the out put of the function in a text box inside the GUI window instead of the python shell, please help, here is my code so far...

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def number(event):
    x = 420
    while True:
        x +=420
        print(x^70)

button_1 = Button(root, text="Start...")
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", number)
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks Harvey

Comment: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find it hard to constantly insert a value into a widget. The widget does not update with each insert. You can think of it has having a temporary variable for it. It can be accessed during the loop (as shown with print). However you'll notice that the widget itself doesn't update until the loop is over. So if you have `while True` then your widget will never update, and so you won't have the numbers streaming into the widget.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def number():
    x = 420
    while x < 8400: # Limit for example
        x +=420
        textbox.insert(END, str(x^70)+'\n') 
        print(textbox.get(1.0, END)) # Print current contents

button_1 = Button(root, text="Start...", command=number) #Changed bind to command, bind is not really needed with a button
button_1.pack()

textbox = Text(root)
textbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```